# How to fix Flutter's FlexibleSpaceBar widget so it fades into the appbar with Material3

Tags: flutter, material-design, sliverappbar, material3

So 'upgrading' to material3 appears to break FlexibleSpaceBar, as you scroll down I had it so it faded into the appbar colour.

Upgrading to Material3, as you scroll the appbar changes from the colour white, to a shade of based of `colorSchemeSeed:Color(0xFF925c48),`

So a light brown colour. As the FlexibleSpaceBar moves up the screen to meet it, it fades to white, the Appbar's former colour.

It maybe attaining this from my ThemeData:

```
scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
canvasColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
```

So I looked at the screen's Scaffold backgroundColor and that isn't white. So it's not fading to that. FlexibleSpaceBar doesn't have a fadeToColorOnCollapse property.

I've looked at FlexibleSpaceBar various child widgets and none really has a color that would be useful. I'm a bit lost.

Has Material3 broken this feature?

```
    return NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: (widget.neighbour.picUrl ?? "") != ""
                  ? (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 4/3) : 256, //300,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background:
                    profilePicWidget,
title: Text("Dummy title"),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body:
```

[image: uncollapsed FlexibleSpaceBar]
Uncollapsed FlexibleSpaceBar

[image: collapsing FlexibleSpaceBar]
Semi collapsed FlexibleSpaceBar, colour fading away

[image: collapsed FlexibleSpaceBar]
collapsed FlexibleSpaceBar, faded to white, not the Appbar's material3 Colour